# How to make a div corner oval shaped?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

using css i want the corner of a div section oval shaped.

```
.c {
height: 10em;
background: radial-gradient(circle 50px at 50% 100%, transparent 50px, rgba(84, 82, 94, 0.8) 50px);
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 100%, circle, transparent 50px, rgba(84, 82, 94, 0.8) 50px);
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code to give the oval shape of your div:-

```
.myclass{border:1px;
-moz-border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;   
-khtml-border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
border-radius:14px 14px 14px 14px;
}
```

You can adjust the corners if the oval by increasing and decreasing the values of four corners like
border-radius:25px 25px 14px 14px;
etc.

Answer (score 3):

it's simple

```
#oval {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}
```

`-moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;` support previous versions of firefox.
`-webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;` support previous versions of chrome.